# Return the uploaded file name in php

Tags: php, wordpress

I am uploading a file using forms in wordpress and I want to print the name of the file that is bieng uploaded but I get empty result.

Below is my code

html

```
<form id="myform" action="" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
<span style="margin-right:20px;">SELECT THE CATEGORY:</span>
<select name="category" id="category" style="background-color:brown;color:#ffffff;">
    <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Please select a competition category</option>
    <option value="Cutie Pie">Cutie Pie</option>
    <option value="Chubby">Chubby</option>
    <option value="Dimples">Dimples</option>
</select>   <br><br>
 <input type="file" name="file" style="margin-top:12px;">
    <br><br>

<input name="upload" type="submit" value="klk"/>
</form>
<div id="result"></div>
```

php code I am using to fetch and print file name

```
$file=$_FILES['file'];
 $name = $file['name'];
echo basename($name);
```

but I am getting empty result ... kindly help

Comment: can't use anything in $_FILES until you've verified that an upload was performed and succeeded, e.g.  `if ($_FILES['file']['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) { die("upload failed"); }`

Answer (score 0):

First you need to receive the file correctly, then you can get it's name like this:

File `up.php`

```
$uploaddir = './upload/'; //give this dir write permissions
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['uploadFile']['name']);

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadFile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
    //now you can get the filename
    $file = basename($uploadfile);
    echo "<div id='result'>File <b>$file</b> is valid, and was successfully uploaded.</div>";

} else {
echo <<< LOB
    <form id="myform" action="up.php" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
    <span style="margin-right:20px;">SELECT THE CATEGORY:</span>
    <select name="category" id="category" style="background-color:brown;color:#ffffff;">
    <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Please select a competition category</option>
    <option value="Cutie Pie">Cutie Pie</option>
    <option value="Chubby">Chubby</option>
    <option value="Dimples">Dimples</option>
    </select>   <br><br>
    <input type="file" name="uploadFile" style="margin-top:12px;">
    <br><br>
    <input name="upload" type="submit" value="klk"/>
    </form>
LOB;
}
```

This is just a short sample to get you going, you should **improve this code**,  by verifying if the file extension is correct so you don't get a `php` file uploaded to your server...

Comment: my problem is that I am using ajax and I have disabled the normal submit behavior of the form

Comment: ok to include the ajax I'll start a new thread or a new question